# WiFi disconnects once I select Charles Proxy Certificate on Android Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge (Physical device)

Tags: android, ssl, mobile, proxy, charles-proxy

Here's a bit of my background. I'm a Mobile Test Engineer with little to no programming. Here's what I'm doing...

1. I've downloaded Charles Proxy.
2. I've downloaded the certificate for Android.
3. I made sure both laptop and Android device are on the same network.
4. I went to WiFi> Modify Settings> Entered the Local IP and Port number.
5. I've selected charles certificate.

My wifi disconnects and it won't authenticate even with correct password. I did not have this issue with iOS device at all. I've searched high and low here and couldn't find the answers. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Where do you select the charles certificate? In the wifi settings?

Comment: When you long press on the wifi network> Modify Network> Scroll down and you can see the "CA Certificate" drop down. That's where I select Charles certificate.